# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' | Python

Tags: python

```
h = s * math.tan(a * 3.14/180) - g * s * s / (v**2 * math.cos(a*3.14/180)**2 * 2)
```

gives:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Full code:

```
import math

g = 9.81
s = 25
v = float(txtv.get())
a = float(txta.get())
h = s * math.tan(a * 3.14/180) - g * s * s / (v**2 * math.cos(a*3.14/180)**2 * 2)


window = Tk()  
window.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение PythonRu")  
window.geometry('400x250')  
lbls = Label(window, text="Ввод переменной S:")  
lbls.grid(column=0, row=0)  
txts = Entry(window,width=10)  
txts.grid(column=1, row=0)  

lblv = Label(window, text="Ввод переменной Vo:")  
lblv.grid(column=0, row=1)  
txtv = Entry(window,width=10)  
txtv.grid(column=1, row=1)  

lbla = Label(window, text="Ввод переменной a:")  
lbla.grid(column=0, row=2)  
txta = Entry(window,width=10)  
txta.grid(column=1, row=2)
```

Help please

Comment: 1- what is `txtv`, 2- what do you expect `"Ваше значение Vo"**2` to yield?

Comment: yes. In the int type

Answer (score 0):

`s` is a string (hence the quation marks). You need to either remove the quotation marks or convert it to a numeric type (e.g. `int(s)`) before using it in an arithmetic operation.

Edit:
Didn't see the `v` and `a` variable being returned by `.get()` (Tkinter?). Here you need to convert. Since it's not sure it's an integer, I'd use `float()`.

Comment: `v` and `a` are strings too. It may be helpful to find out what OP expects those to do.

Comment: I removed the quotation marks. Same mistake

Comment: How to convert v and a to int type?

Comment: `v` is `"Ваше значение Vo:"`. If you could convert that to an `int`, what would you expect the result to be?

Comment: Edited the code above. Look

Comment: I expect what you want is `v = int(txtv.get())`.

Comment: Fixed the code by replacing it with the float type. Did I do the right thing?

Comment: It should be correct as long as you only enter numbers in your `Entry` fields.